# compile Error: User defined type not defined VB 6.0

Tags: reference, vb6

I have got this error at:

```
Dim frmD as frmDocument
```

I am using VB 6.0 under windows XP, Can please any body tell me which reference should i need to add?

this is exact code:

```
Private Sub LoadNewDoc()
    Static lDocumentCount As Long
    Dim frmD As frmDocument  // at this line i got error, User defined type not defined
    lDocumentCount = lDocumentCount + 1
    Set frmD = New frmDocument
    frmD.Caption = "Document " & lDocumentCount
    frmD.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: You should add a reference to whatever contains `frmDocument`, which is not a system type or known to anyone. Probably there is supposed to be a form named that. Most often it is in the same project, so if it is not there, someone might have deleted it.

Comment: when i write Dim frmD as frmDocument. after "as" i don't get option frmDocument in intellicence. so, how i be able to get frmDocument option in intellience, so for this which reference should i add?

Comment: You should add a reference to whatever contains `frmDocument`, which is not a system type or known to anyone. Only you know what that might be.

Comment: is frmDocument a form in your project?